# Cannot start and register the chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following the hyperleger fabric chaincode setup instructions: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/Chaincode-setup

I'm using docker toolbox and a peer is running in one terminal (docker-compose up).

In another docker terminal I try to start and register the chaincode: 
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051 ./chaincode_example02

I get this error:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Update: I'm using the docker-compose.yml from the docs:

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

`docker ps` gives:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CRE
ATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
35050760e1df        hyperledger/fabric-peer         "sh -c 'sleep 5; peer"   21
minutes ago      Up 2 minutes                            option3_vp0_1
209132c7f059        hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc   "membersrvc"             21
minutes ago      Up 2 minutes                            option3_membersrvc_1
```

and `docker-machine ls` gives:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DO
CKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.109:2376           v1
.12.3
```

So I tried also to start and register the chaincode with:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=192.168.99.109:7051 ./chaincode_example02
```

Comment: Try to change peer.address and listenAddress to `0.0.0.0:7051` in `peer/core.yaml`

Comment: it was already like that, i'm using http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your peer is not reachable at `0.0.0.0.7051` . To check if you have a peer listening on 7051 , use the command: 
 `netstat -lnptu| grep 7051`

Try setting `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS` to either the public or the private IP of the host instead of `0.0.0.0`

Also verify that you have forwarded the port **7051**  from the docker container to the host.

Comment: the port 7051 is listening and I tryed to map ports "7051:7051" in the docker-compose.yml, but sill get the error.

Comment: Can you try setting the CORE_PEER_ADDRESS to either the private IP(lo inet addr) or the public IP(eth0 inet addr) of this host ? instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: Ok, I tried with private and public IP, error continues: Chaincode log level not provided.

Comment: Okay .but this solves the problem in your original question doesn't it ? The next error should probably go into another question :)

Comment: Can you update the question with your docker compose file and peer log ?